# Drupal - installing a legacy project on local machine

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to install a project from gitbhub on a local machine. After cloning the repo, and importing the DB. I have setup the DB local settings in the `sites/default/setttings.php` file:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal_project',
      'username' => 'homestead',
      'password' => 'secret',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

And then I have tried to open the project in the browser to install it, but first I got the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use lexical variable $value as a parameter name in
>   components/select.inc on line 765

After fixing this I got the new error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /home/vagrant/Projects/presafe/sites/all/themes/sasson/phamlp/sass/script/SassScriptLexer.php
>   on line 100

And after increasing the time I got the new one:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 4096 bytes) in
>   /home/vagrant/Projects/presafe/sites/all/themes/sasson/phamlp/sass/script/SassScriptLexer.php
>   on line 98

How can I fix this error and install my project?

Comment: You have to fill right local DB configuration in settings.php

Comment: You have to increase you max_exectuion_time value in php.ini or .htacess
for more details refer this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: There is no settings.php file in the project

Answer (score 0):

Increase you max_exectuion_time value in your php to change the value refer [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04)

or use htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried to do that in .htacess, but I got the same error again

Comment: Then try to change max_exectuion_time in your php.ini file in Apache or Nginx

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04 refer this to change in Apache

Comment: Increasing the time, just gets me new errors, I don't think that was the problem, something in the setup or the script is wrong